# VMware player shared folders on Linux host

Tags: linux, vmware-workstation, shared-folders

I haven't been able to find any shared folder settings on my VMWare Workstation 12 player (non-commercial use only).

I tried searching all the documentation online, and it makes so many references to the "shared folder" part of the VM menu, yet I see none here.

Is it something that requires upgrading to full version?

Answer (score 2):

**First** goto your VM Image, click on edit, go to **options tab**, you will see **shared** title with yellow folder icon, turn it on, and add the folder you want to share. 
Turn your Guest **ON** and for example you have macOS or Ubuntu as guest OS, check your home folder, you will have network available, browse that it will have shared folder, which will contain your shared folder, drives & files

**Note**: your image must not be running or in suspend mode. your guest OS must be switched off to turn sharing on,